# What is the opposite for prepare() in swift Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, segue

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == Storyboards.AuthenticationStoryboard.Segues.forgotPasswordSegue {
            guard let navigationController = segue.destination as? UINavigationController else { return }
            guard let forgotPasswordViewController = navigationController.viewControllers.first as? ForgotPasswordEmailViewController else { return }
            forgotPasswordViewController.viewModel.email.value = viewModel.model.email.value
        }
        if segue.identifier == Storyboards.AuthenticationStoryboard.Segues.showPhoneViewSegue {
            guard let destinationViewController = segue.destination as? EnterPhoneViewController else { return }
            destinationViewController.successFallbackViewController = self
        }
    }
```

this is the current prepare function that is overriden. As far as my knowledge this function is called before the segue is executed. similarly is there any function that can be written in order to carry out instructions once the segue has been completed.

Comment: the destinationVC's viewDidLoad() will be called anyway if and when the segue executes.

Comment: Typically `viewWill/DidDisappear` will be called.  In some cases it won't, such as a pop-over segue